# Excel-to-SQL stored procedure with multiple parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I have a stored procedure with four parameters, I'm trying to connect it to an Excel 2010 workbook but I'm having difficulty passing multiple parameters.

I followed the steps outlined in [Running a SQL Stored Procedure in Excel](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/running-a-sql-stored-procedure-from-excel-with-dynamic-parameters/) and was able to connect my stored procedure to Excel and pass one parameter.

But after I got that to work I had to modify my stored procedure and add three more parameters and now I can't figure out the syntax for the command text in my Excel connection to pass multiple parameters.

My stored procedure name is `[VIDIR].[_cornie_Report_Shipped_Serial_Numbers]` and I used the following VBA code in my Excel workbook to successfully refresh the connection with only one parameter.

```
Sub RefreshQuery()
   With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("VIDIR3 Arborg_Test_App country").OLEDBConnection
       .CommandText = "[VIDIR].[_cornie_Report_Shipped_Serial_Numbers] '%" & Range("C3").Value & "%'"
   End With

   ActiveWorkbook.Connections("VIDIR3 Arborg_Test_App country").Refresh
End Sub
```

The four parameter names in the modified stored procedure are:

```
@BillName    varchar(60)
,@ShipName   varchar(60)
,@Item       varchar(40)
,@FamilyCode varchar(40)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the logic described in https://superuser.com/questions/294779/pass-a-cell-contents-as-a-parameter-to-an-excel-query-in-excel-2007 (second part of the first answer, involving `CreateParameter` and the `Parameters` collection. See also http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=170413 for another example.